# edx platform table doesnt exist after migrate

Tags: django, edx

I created an app under edx-platform/djangoapps.
Under that I created a model.
After that I ran

```
paver update_db -s devstack
```

to update database and make migrations.

I login to django shell via

```
./manage.py lms --settings aws shell
```

and import my model via

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
```

it imports successfully without errors but when i ran

```
MyModel.objects.all()
```

I encounter this error:

```
DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'edxapp.myapp_mymodel' doesn't exist")
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added your new Django application to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in the [LMS settings](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/93faba006c627c921a9b12efe47d64f342cd5e06/lms/envs/common.py#L1671):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'yourapp',
```

Then re-run the lms migrations:

```
$ paver update_db -s devstack
```

Comment: It worked the first time. But when I make changes to my model and ran paver update_db -s devstack it doesnt update the table in mysql